# I would like to know the difference between Database, Data warehouse, Data mining and Big Data?

Tags: database

Since I am new to the word Database. I would like to know the differences. Please explain with examples. What is Database, Data mining, Data warehouse and Big Data?

Comment: if you google, numerous answers will emerge

Comment: What amount of effort have you yourself put into finding this out?

Comment: what else would you like ? lottery numbers as well ! kkkkk

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using http://bigdatauniversity.com/

It has free relevant and updated course materials on the topics you seek. Topics such as Hadoop and Data Mining are covered and this gives you access to tools to practise.

- **Big data** is a buzzword, or catch-phrase, used to describe a massive volume of both structured and unstructured data that is so
  large that it's difficult to process using traditional database and
  software techniques.
- A **database** is an organized collection of data. The data is
  typically organized to model aspects of reality in a way that
  supports processes requiring information.
- **Data Mining** is an analytic process designed to explore data (usually large amounts of data typically business or market related
  also known as "big data") in search of consistent patterns and/or systematic relationships between variables, and then to validate the
  findings by applying the detected patterns to new subsets of data.
  The ultimate goal of data mining is prediction - and predictive data
  mining is the most common type of data mining and one that has the
  most direct business applications.
- *StatSoft* defines **data warehousing** as a process of organizing the
  storage of large, multivariate data sets in a way that facilitates
  the retrieval of information for analytic purposes.